# Remove elements from a list which occur in another list as many times as they occur in the other list

Tags: python

I have list1 and list2. list2 is a group of words that have to be removed from list1, for example:

```
list1=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i','i', 'me', 'me']

list2=["i","me"]
```

Output should be:

```
list3=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my','i','i','me']
```

Similar questions have been asked but they remove all duplicates also. But I want to remove the elements from list1 as many times as they occur in list2

Comment: Iterate over `list2`, calling `list1.remove()` for each (or `list3.remove()` after copying list1.)

Answer (score 2):

Memory inefficient for long lists, but will preserve ordering:

```
list1=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i','i', 'me', 'me']
list2=["i","me"]

list3 = list1[:]                # Copy list1 -> list3
for rem_word in list2:          # Iterate over list2 as rem_word
    list3.remove(rem_word)      # Remove rem_word from list3

print(list3)
```

If the elements of list2 are guaranteed to be in list1 (in sufficient quantity to remove them all).

Otherwise,

```
list1=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i','i', 'me', 'me']
list2=["i","me","zzz"]

list3 = list1[:]                # Copy list1 -> list3
for rem_word in list2:          # Iterate over list2 as rem_word
    try:
        list3.remove(rem_word)  # Remove rem_word from list3
    except ValueError: pass

print(list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
from collections import Counter
list1=['paste', 'text', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i','i', 'me', 'me']
list2=["i","me", "text"]
d = Counter(list2)
new_d = [c for i, c in enumerate(list1) if c not in d or sum(a == c for a in list1[:(i if i < len(list1)-1 else i+1)]) >= d[c]]
```

Output:

```
['paste', 'text', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'my', 'i', 'i', 'me']
```

Comment: I love what this answer is doing, but it does not work for me when other words from `list1` are used in `list2`.